# 'com.itextpdf.text.html.WebColors' is deprecated

Tags: java, itext

I am using **iText** library and having a code snippet given below:

```
BaseColor sectionFontColor = WebColors.getRGBColor("#ffffff");
```

Getting a warning message:

```
'com.itextpdf.text.html.WebColors' is deprecated
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: it is nice that you added a bounty, but what actually *is* your question? You merely state that you get a message (from whom? The compiler? The program in a log file? Or a message box? Or...) but you don't tell what you want to know. Do you want to know why `Webcolors` is deprecated? Or whether in current versions it already has been removed? Or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using **iText** version above **5.5.2**. `WebColors` is deprecated from **5.5.2** onwards as per docs.

`BaseColor` class supports default colors: `WHITE`, `LIGHT_GRAY`, `GRAY`, `DARK_GRAY`, `BLACK`, `RED`, `PINK`, `ORANGE`, `YELLOW`, `GREEN`, `MAGENTA`, `CYAN` & `BLUE`

If you want to generate a different color apart from default colors, then you have to pass RGB values in the constructor of `BaseColor`.

Example:

```
// #ffffff hex code is for white color
BaseColor sectionFontColor = BaseColor.WHITE;

// if you want to have a different color, for example, Purple (#674ea7)
BaseColor sectionFontColor = new BaseColor(103, 78, 167);
```

**Note:** First parameter being the **red** value, second parameter being the **green** value & third parameter being the **blue** value in the `BaseColor` constructor.

I have used this website [color-hex.com](https://www.color-hex.com/color/674ea7) to generate the hex code and RGB values for a particular color.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't give much info, i'm going to make a guess, hope it works.
Use https://api.itextpdf.com/iText/java/7.2.4/com/itextpdf/kernel/colors/Color.html or ignore the deprecation warning.